# Creating a method of IEnumerable type that takes in generic type

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I created an IEnumerable method that takes in an IEnumerable of type PERSON which swaps the first names and last names of the employee (They are currently adding them into a database in a single field ("John Smith", "Craig Robertson") etc.

I have another IEnumerable called ProjectPerson which has similar but different data that I would like to swap the first and last names of as well.

Both IEnumerables have "Name" as a field so the code works fine for both, I just want to be able to re-use this code without creating an overload with `IEnumerabe<Person>` and another with `IEnumerable<ProjectPerson>` but the same code inside each.

Is there a way to set up an IEnumerable method that can be used by different Types? Maybe passing in the Type as an argument then cast?

I have created an interface called IPerson:

```
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Name { get; set;}
    }
```

and I have the following:

```
public class Person: IPerson {..}

public class ProjectPerson: IPerson {..}
```

My Method looks like this:

```
private void IEnumerable<IPerson> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<IPerson> persons)
{
    foreach (var employee in persons)
    {
        //do the swapping
    }
    return persons;
}
```

I am calling this method elsewhere in the class using these two lines:

```
_projectPerson = SwapFirstAndLastNames(projectpersons) 

_person = SwapFirstAndLastNames(person);
```

Using the above I get an error on that method saying "Cannot convert from ProjectPerson to IPerson (same with Person to IPerson) and also "The best overload method match for SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable) has some invalid arguments.

Both person and projectPerson are of type IENumerable (as are the underlined ones) and the data used in each is used elsewhere to fill datagrids and such like. So i'm basically looking for a single method that takes any type of IEnumerable, swaps the IEnumerable.Name field around (i've got the code to do this already) and then returns the swapped IEnumerable data. I have this working on a single Type.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the following syntax to define the method.

```
private void IEnumerable<T> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<T> persons) where T : IPerson
{
    foreach (var employee in persons)
    {
       //do the 
    }
    return persons;
}
```

Note the `where T : IPerson` this constrains your method so it can only be called by classes which implement this interface (you wouldn't want someone to pass ints in for example!). You'd implement this interface which both ProjectPerson and Person and include all the fields your method needs to run (presumably firstname/lastname).

The interface would look something like

```
public interface IPerson
{
  Firstname {get;set;}
  Lastname {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You were first with this answer, I wonder why it's not being upvoted

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree after seeing your answer, the generic matches the OP's original pattern but there's no need for it if you use the interface. However I didn't want to edit mine to match yours or we'd just end up with duplicate answers!

Answer (score 5):

May be the soultion is to *extract an interface*?

```
  public interface IPerson {
    String FirstName {get; set}
    String LastName {get; set}
  }

  public class Person: IPerson {...}

  public class ProjectPerson: IPerson {...}

  private void IEnumerable<T> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<T> persons) 
    where T: IPerson
  {
    foreach (var employee in persons)
    {
        // You can operate with FirstName/LastName as you like here 
    }
    return persons;
  }
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with the same solution as me (which is clearly the best ;-))

Comment: Weird.. I'd have thought an abstract Person would have been the appropriate solution here.

Comment: @Lews Therin: it depends on what classes Person and ProjectPerson are inherited; one can always exctract an interface and it's an easy task to do, on the contrary changing the base class(es) can be very complicated problem.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Maybe.. maybe not. But using an interface gives the impression that Person can be instantiated. If it can in this case, then that's fine I guess.

Comment: @LewsTherin if you're going down that route you could also create an extension method on the interface itself - no need for a base class

Comment: @Liath No way. Extension methods are a terrible idea imo.

Comment: @LewsTherin each to their own

Answer (score 5):

I would create an interface that contains all relevant properties, like

```
public interface INamedEntity
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Both of your classes should implement it:

```
public class Person : INamedEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }         
}

public class ProjectPerson : INamedEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

Now you are able to create an extension method for `IEnumerable<INamedEntity>` to swap `FirstName` and `Lastname` which you can use for `Persons` and `ProjectPersons`:

```
public static void SwapFirstAndLastNames(this IEnumerable<INamedEntity> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        string oldLastName = person.LastName;
        person.LastName = person.FirstName;
        person.FirstName = oldLastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, generic is not required here

Comment: I like this answer - I don't believe generics are required if you use the interface.

Comment: When I try to use this Method:

_projectPerson = SwapFirstAndLastNames(projectPersons)

I get an error as it's trying to convert type IEnumerable to an interface (the IPerson / INamedEntity)

My Method is returning an IEnumerable -- > 

public static IEnumerable<IPerson> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<IPerson> persons)

Comment: @iandavidson1982: That's an extension method(it does not need to be one). You can either call it on an `IEnumerable<INamedEntity>` as if it would exist on that type or simply as a static method. However, it is `void` so it doesn't return anything. Masybe you need to show what you have tried in your question since it difficult to understand in comments and others could help too.

Comment: Hi Tim. I have created an interface and changed my Person and ProjectPerson classes to use this interface. I am using private IEnumerable<IPerson> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<IPerson> persons) {..} which I am calling using the following two lines -> _person = SwapFirstAndLastNames(person); and _projectPerson = SwapFirstAndLastNames(projectpersons);

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have used / tried and the errors I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Extract super class or make interface, then you can do:

```
private void IEnumerable<T> SwapFirstAndLastNames(IEnumerable<T> persons) where T : PersonSuperClass
{ 
... 
}
```